# javascript is there a way to clean up a string multiple times in a clean way

Tags: javascript, json, replace

I'm trying to clean up a JSON string (that was converted from a json object) and I found that many people use the .replace() method to do so. However, in doing so my code looked like this:

```
scrape(url).then(result => {
  final = JSON.stringify(result);
  final = final.replace(/['"]+/g, "");
  final = final.replace(/[{]+/g, "");
  final = final.replace(/[}]+/g, "");
  final = final.replace(/[:]+/g, ": ");
  final = final.replace(/,+/g, ";");
  return final;
});
```

While this method does work returning 'final' in the way i want it,  it does not seem very efficient and the code is really clunky. My end goal is to remove quotes, curly brackets, replace ':' with ': ' and change all commas to semi colons. Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

EDIT: 
The input string looks something like this:

```
{
  '$primary': '#ea80fc',
  '$p_light': '#ffb2ff',
  '$p_dark': '#b64fc8',
  '$secondary': '#b64fc8',
  '$s_light': '#f9683a',
  '$s_dark': '#870000'
}
```

Comment: Rather than "using replace", what are you trying to do? I.e. _why_ are you cleaning your string? What are you going to use it in that requires you to replace certain character (classes) with empty strings or semi colons? Because asking how best to do _that_ job is going to yield far better answers.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for the pointer! I was aiming to convert the json string into variables that could be used in scss format, so something like: 
'variable name: hexcode' (without quotation marks)

Comment: Follow-up question: what does your input string data _actually_ look like? I.e. what is the JSON you're parsing that leads to you having strings that even need converting at all, instead of getting preformatted CSS-legal strings in your JSON?

Comment: I edited the post and included the JSON that I was trying to parse. What do you mean by preformatted CSS-legal strings?

Comment: CSS has a rigid specification that says exactly which characters are legal, in which positions, and which are not. So rather than a chain of replacements, it's _far_ easier to go "remove anything that _isn't_ a legal character" with a single replacement. With that said: if that is the JSON you get, why run a regex on the entire JSON string at all? Better to use JSON.parse to verify it's legal JSON first (remember to `try/catch`!) and then use something like `Object.keys(parsed).forEach(key => { /* do something with key and parsed[key] */ });`?

Comment: I tried parsing and manipulating the JSON object directly but I always end up with apostrophes around the keys/values and also commas at the end of each key/value pair, and also the curly brackets at the start/end. The end goal that i got from using the replace statements was intended eg: $primary: #ea80fc; $p_light: #ffb2ff; $p_dark: #b64fc8; etc. and needs to be able to be copy-pasted directly into an scss file. For now i think i will just go with this approach as i do not fully understand how to manipulate the keys/values properly in Object form to exactly how i want

Comment: Very important technical terms note: there is no such thing as a "JSON object". There is JSON, which is a single long string that needs to be parsed before you can "do" anything to it, and there is a plain JS object that you get from running `JSON.parse`. So there is no such thing as "manipulation the JSON object". With that said, based on the object you're showing, let me write an answer that explains how to turn that into legal SCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your actual data, where after `JSON.parse` you have the following structure:

```js
{
  '$primary': '#ea80fc',
  '$p_light': '#ffb2ff',
  '$p_dark': '#b64fc8',
  '$secondary': '#b64fc8',
  '$s_light': '#f9683a',
  '$s_dark': '#870000'
}
```

turning this into legal SCSS doesn't require a long chain of replaces applied to the JSON string at all. It just requires parsing the JSON to plain JS object, and then iterating over the key/values to form an SCSS string:

```js
function jsonToSCSS(stringdata=``, data={}) {
  /* JSON.parse can throw. Always be ready for that. */
  try { data = JSON.parse(stringdata); }
  catch (e) { console.warn(e); return ``; }

  return Object.keys(data)
               .map(key => `${key}: ${data[key]};`)
               .join('\n');
}
```

And done. The output of that function is now a normal, formatted string:

```css
$primary: #ea80fc;
$p_light: #ffb2ff;
$p_dark: #b64fc8;
$secondary: #b64fc8;
$s_light: #f9683a;
$s_dark: #870000;
```

Which you can now write into whatever file you need it written into, either directly, or itself wrapped in formatting:

```js
const SCSS = jsonToSCSS(inputdata);
const qualified = `.someclass { ${SCSS} }`;
```

Answer (score 1):

More simplified

```
scrape(url).then(result => {
  return JSON.stringify(result.replace(/['"{}]+/g, "").replace(/[:]+/g, ":").replace(/,+/g, ";"));
});
```